# Visual Studio 2013 fatal error c1083:cannot open include file "stadfx.h" no such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, stdafx.h

Hi guys I was trying to learn C++ during which my first program (the infamous hello world program) had problems i repeatedly get the C1083 fatal error include file "stdafx.h"not found no such file or directory. Any help would be appreciated
thanks in advance.

P.S. If possible please provide a extra detailed answer because i am still trying to learn C++ and I am the newest noob here.

Here is the code

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include < iostream >

int main()    
{    
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::cout endl;
        std::cout << "My First Program" << std::cout endl;
        return 0;    
}
```

Comment: ;p thanks for the link i think i have been using the wrong kind of project    format thank you very much #apokal

Comment: `std::cout endl` should be `std::endl`.